# A big circle has a small circle fixed in a position within the Highcharts

Tags: reactjs, highcharts, bubble-chart

I'm trying to create a custom packed bubble chart but I can't seem to achieve the design I want. I've searched and tried various methods in Highcharts documentation, but it seems like I still haven't found what I'm looking for. I hope you can provide some suggestions to help me, thank you so much !

this is my code

```
import classNames from "classnames/bind";
import styles from "./CircleGrid.module.scss";
import Highcharts from "highcharts";
import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
import More from "highcharts/highcharts-more";
More(Highcharts);

type Tpackedbubble = {
data?: any;
backgroundColor?: any;
};
enter image description here
const fakeData = [
{ name: "A", value: 12, color: "#000000" },
{ name: "B", value: 50, color: "#000000" },
{ name: "C", value: 2, color: "#000000" },
];

const CircleGrid = ({
data = fakeData,
backgroundColor = "white",
}: Tpackedbubble) = {
const cx = classNames.bind(styles);

const options = {
chart: {
type: "packedbubble",
renderTo: "container",
backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
},

    tooltip: {
      useHTML: true,
      headerFormat: "",
      pointFormat: "<b>Member :</b> {point.value} </sub>",
    },
    
    title: {
      useHTML: false,
      text: "",
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    credits: {
      text: "",
    },
    plotOptions: {
      packedbubble: {
        minSize: "50%",
        maxSize: "200%",
        zMin: 0,
        zMax: 300,
        layoutAlgorithm: {
          splitSeries: false,
          gravitationalConstant: 0.02,
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: "{point.name}",
          style: {
            color: "white",
            textOutline: "none",
            fontWeight: "500",
            fontSize: "15",
            fontFamily: "CircularStd",
          },
        },
      },
    },
    
    series: [
      {
        data,
      },
    ] as TSeries[],

};

return (
<div style={{ width: "100%", height: "440px" }}\>
<HighchartsReact
highcharts={Highcharts}
options={options}
containerProps={{
style: { marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: "auto", height: "inherit" },
}}
/\>
\</div\>
);
};

export default CircleGrid;
```

My bubble chart [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqpPR.png)

This is I trying [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L80v.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Highcharts.SVGRenderer` class to add custom SVG elements on a chart. In your case, the best seems to be to add labels with `circle` shape to every bubble point. For example:

```
  chart: {
    ...,
    events: {
      render() {
        const chart = this;

        chart.series[0].points.forEach(point => {
          const centerX = point.plotX;
          const centerY = point.plotY;
          const radius = point.radius;

          const halfRadiusX = radius / Math.sqrt(2);
          const halfRadiusY = radius / Math.sqrt(2);

          const pointX = centerX + halfRadiusX;
          const pointY = centerY - halfRadiusY;

          if (!point.customCircle) {
            point.customCircle = chart.renderer.label('2', null, null, 'circle').attr({
              fill: 'gray',
              'stroke-width': 1,
              width: 30,
              height: 30,
              'text-align': 'center',
              zIndex: 3
            }).css({
              color: 'white'
            }).add();
          }

          point.customCircle.attr({
            x: pointX + chart.plotLeft,
            y: pointY + chart.plotTop
          });
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/zLu3192h/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer